# Center align too wide table (longtable) in rmarkdown latex

Tags: latex, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I have a table that is too wide and is therefore spilling into the right margin.

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39435/how-can-i-center-a-too-wide-table) on tex exchange which gives the latex solution using `\makebox`.

As I am not an expert in latex and my table is a longtable I was unable to implement that even in latex.

My preference is for a solution in rmarkdown itself. I am using kable if that makes any difference.

Posting through mobile so couldn't add an example.

EDIT:
For clarification, I am looking for a solution which works specifically for long tables and the horizontal spill is symmetrical in both right and left margins.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic solution for `kableExtra` is:

````
```{r table, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(gt) #dataset gtcars is here
library(kableExtra)
dt <- head(gtcars)

dt %>%
  kbl() %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("scale_down", "hold_position"))
```
````

[image]

About **fontsizes** look [there](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_sizes%2C_families%2C_and_styles)

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I don't want to use scale_down as I want to control font size also. Main objective is to make the spill symmetrical in both left and right margins

Comment: @Dayne look to an addition

Comment: thanks...will try to use and revert. Just tk be sure, this is to be implemented in tex file right? I tried with the makebox thing also in tex file but didn't work probably because it is a longtable.

Comment: @Dayne No, all in Rmd-file.

Comment: So I tried but same error comes..related to 'Missing \endgroup inserted'. My knowledge of latex is only basic but seems like this is related to the fact that my table is a longtable.

Comment: Also as per you latest edit, the table is inserted in running text...would be okay if I used regular code block? When tried the latter same error had come.

Comment: @Dayne No, not in code block. But as written there: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text - better to use a smaller font, as I said you too earlier. You can also rotate your table...

Comment: Please don't use `\resizebox` for elements which contain text. This will result in a suboptimal choice of glyph shapes.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes, I saw your post :)

Comment: @manro Thanks for removing this part! :)